# Hide/add legend to graph with conditions

Tags: excel, vba, graph, excel-formula

I have 2 columns of data for my chart, but the second one is optional (with an IF formula).

I want the legend to only show the relevant series.

Because the legend is visible even if there is no data for the second column, I wrote this in the cell for the series name:

```
=IF(…………;"blabla";"")
```

Now the legend has no label and only the (yellow dashed) line appears:

[image]

How can I hide both the label and the line in this legend if the series has no data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA to realize this.

in Excel 2013 onward model
you can use Chart.FullSeriesCollection to select your series and toggle its Isfiltered properties

Like

```
If.....Then
   ChartObjects("xxxx").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
Else
   ChartObjects("xxxx").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = False
End if
```

If you are using old excel, like excel 2007, excel 2010.. you should only use Chart.legend.legendEntries(2).Delete to get rid of the legend. if you wanna toggle it back, you should use chart.hasLegend = false, Chart.hasLegend = true to make it back